# Подскажите практическую часть моей теории )) Присовение класса при активной переменной

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Сразу скажу я полный 0 в js и все что с ним связано. Но как понимаю решение именно на нем.

P.S в  ходе мозгокопательства пришел к выводу что можно все упростить
есть триге (a oneclick="AddWishlist") , нужно по нажатию на этот тригер , присвоить div елементу c id="myid" новый класс , к примеру "newclass". Как такую штуку записать правильно?

такой вариант почему то не работает

```
    <script>
     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
         'use strict';
         let click_on_fa = document.querySelector(".fa-heart"),
         mouse_click = document.querySelector(".wishlist");
         mouse_click.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             click_on_fa.classList.add(".new_clicked");
         });

     });
 </script>
```

Comment: `classList.add(".new_clicked");` — ошибка тут. Это не селектор, а название класса, точка не нужна внутри кавычек.

Comment: убрал точку , вариант всеровно не отрабатывает 
на примере пустой странички да 
на рабочем сайте , почему то нет...

Answer (score 0):

```
Точка в classList.add() не нужна.
Так же отсутствует объявление переменной mouse_click.



<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
</p>
<button>CLICK</button>
</div>


.clicked {
color: #BADA55;
background-color: aqua;
}

p {
color: black;
background-color: green;
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  'use strict';
  const btn = document.querySelector('button');
  const p = document.querySelector('p');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    p.classList.add('clicked');
    });
 });
```

Comment: если открыть простой пример этой страницы то в консоли все отрабатывает , а вот на живом сайте нет(

Comment: не совмем понял ваш пример с button
на сколько понял логику вашего кода то это на тот же класс на который нажали и присваиваеться новый ?

Comment: @VACUUM_scm, исправил, теперь при нажатии на `<button>` класс `clicked` присваивается `<div>`

Comment: подставил свои значения, на сайте не отрабатывает(

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  'use strict';
  const btncompare = document.querySelector('.compare');
  const nstcomapare = document.querySelector('.clickcompare');
  btncompare.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    nstcomapare.classList.add('newclasscompare');
    });
 });
    </script>

Comment: Можно весь код? Хотя бы с этим классом

Comment: весь код чего ? 
скрипт в низу футера , если вы об этом

Comment: Код с классами и html тэгами

Comment: `<div id="newclassfa" class="cart newhcart">
 <a onclick="addToCompare('419');" title="В сравнение" class="compare current-link"><i class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>`
это тригер
это где нужно присвоить
`<div id="newcompare" class="clickcompare">
    <a id="oct-compare" href="http://test.manege.com.ua/index.php?route=product/compare" class="checkout-top"><span id="hoverico"><i class="fa fa-balance-scale"></i></span></a>
   </div>`

Comment: Можно описание классов css?

Comment: да там нету ничего глобального
отступы , падинги ,  сайзы 
просто нету сейчас возможности скопировать